# CSS optimization in terms of LoC

Tags: html, css

A silly question but just curious, say I have a css in the following format,

```
.name1{color: black}
.name2{color: red}
.name3{color: yellow}
```

Now I need to add some other property like text-decoration: underline on all this three. Instead of adding it in each rule as,

```
.name1{color: black,text-decoration: underline }
.name2{color: red,text-decoration: underline }
.name3{color: yellow,text-decoration: underline }
```

Is there a better way of doing it like clubbing them together for just the text-decoration: underline  and use their color property as such. Something like inheritance or over-riding in OOPs.

Thanks,
Abi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.name1,
.name2,
.name3 {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

You could also add a class to each element in the HTML and reference it once in the CSS.

Also, the property delimiter is `;`, not `,`.